# subtypes/supertypes with upper bounded generics

Tags: kotlin, types, typing

learning kotlin & have been reading about subtypes/supertypes and variance from https://typealias.com/guides/star-projections-and-how-they-work/ & generally, this website. I have a question that I don't think is covered (or maybe I'm just confused). Suppose you have a

```
open class A
open class B : A()
```

Pretty clearly A is a supertype of B. But what about the following?

```
open class Foo<T : A> {
fun doSomething(temp: T)
}

open class SubFoo : Foo<B>() {
}
```

Is SubFoo a subtype of Foo?

```
fun input(input: Foo<A>)
fun output(): SubFoo<B>

val inputParam = SubFoo()

input(inputParam) // works?

val ret: Foo<A> = output() // also works??
```

Intuitively I think the above works as desired, and the answer to the above question is yes. But I'm not completely sure, nor do I have a concrete explanation other than it resolves in my head. Honestly there's like 3 things going on here, the typing of A/B, the typing of Foo vs SubFoo, and upper bounding, and I think I'm getting lost in it all. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is SubFoo a subtype of Foo?

No because `Foo` is not a type. `Foo<A>` and `Foo<B>` are types. Syntactically, `Foo` on its own is *malformed* unless the type parameter (the thing that goes in the `<>`) can be inferred.

In this case, `SubFoo` is a subtype of `Foo<B>` because it inherits from `Foo<B>`. `SubFoo` does not become a subtype of `Foo<A>` as a result of this though, so these do not work:

```
open class SubFoo : Foo<B>() {
    override doSomething(temp: B) {
       // do something that is specific to B
    }
}

fun input(input: Foo<A>) { }
fun output(): SubFoo = SubFoo()

val inputParam = SubFoo()

input(inputParam) // compiler error

val ret: Foo<A> = output() // compiler error
```

The idea that you also become the subtype of `SomeGenericType<SuperType>` by inheriting `SomeGenericType<Subtype>` is called [*covariance*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#variance). You can make a type parameter of covariant by adding `out` to it. For example, `List<T>` is declared like this:

```
public interface List<out E>
```

So `List<String>` is a subtype of `List<Any>`.

However, this only works if it is safe to do so. In the case of `Foo`, it is not safe at all for its type parameter to be covariant. Consider what would happen if `val ret: Foo<A> = output()` were allowed. I could do:

```
open class C : A()

val ret: Foo<A> = output() // suppose this worked
ret.doSomething(C())
```

From the type checker's perspective, this looks all fine. `ret` is a `Foo<A>`, so its `doSomething` takes an `A`. `C` inherits from `A`, so it can be passed to an `A` parameter.

But what actually happens when this is run? A `SubFoo` is returned by `output()`, and `SubFoo` only accepts `B`s in *its* `doSomething` method. Oopsies!

Comment: So is there ever a way to write these four classes such that  `SubFoo<B>` *is* a subtype, i.e., make the parameter covariant? The answer is no, right? You would simply have to change Foo's API to never input `T`, i.e., private(and importantly, protecting doesn't even work)/completely remove `doSomething`.

Comment: @CoolRobloxKid12 `SubFoo<B>`? You mean `Foo<T>` right? `SubFoo` does not have a type parameter, so there is nothing to make covariant there. `out` can also appear when you use `Foo<T>`, so e.g. `val ret: Foo<out A> = output()` works, and you cannot call `ret.doSomething`.

Comment: sorry, you're right, my question wasn't clear (also with incorrect syntax). I was just hoping if there was a magic bullet to make `SubFoo` a subtype of `Foo<A>` & i was just not being clever but I think I understand now it's not possible without imposing restrictions like specifying `out`